# Parameter in newcommand like part of name in newcommand

Tags: tex-core

i wanna in newcommand in new command use like part of new command

```
\newcommand{\megakommand}[3]{
\newcommand{#1One}{#2#3}
\newcommand{#1Two}{#3#2}
}

\megakommand{\ciferki}{1}{2}
\ciferkiOne -> 12
\ciferkiTwo -> 21
```

but take error like:

This compile didn't produce a PDF. This can happen if:

There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.

The document environment contains no content. If it's empty, please add some content and compile again.

This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.

Answer (score 1):

If the first argument to `\megakommand` *needs* to be a control-sequence name...

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\megakommand}[3]{
  \expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1One\endcsname{#2#3}
  \expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1Two\endcsname{#3#2}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\megakommand{\ciferki}{1}{2}
\ciferkiOne $->$ 12

\ciferkiTwo $->$ 21
\end{document}
```

[image]

By using `\def` here instead of `\newcommand`, it means that the command could overwrite an existing command (rather than throw an error).  It also means argument2 `#2` and `#3` are precluded from containing a paragraph boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing some of the possible syntaxes here which makes it slightly more difficult. Below is a toned-down version, where you pass the control sequence name (not the control sequence itself) and construct the newly-defined control sequences via `\csname`...`\endcsname`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\megakommand}[3]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1One\endcsname{#2#3}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1Two\endcsname{#3#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\megakommand{ciferki}{1}{2}

\verb|\ciferkiOne|: \ciferkiOne

\verb|\ciferkiTwo|: \ciferkiTwo

\end{document}
```